# Hyperparameters of Exponential Smoothing

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I have a large number of time series to forecast on which I would like to evaluate the potential of Exponential Smoothing. However, I am faced with a problem of parameter selection: I dont know how to automatically select the following:

- The trend type: it could be None, additive or multiplicative,
- The seasonality type: it could be None, additive or multiplicative,
- Whether the trend is Damped or not (True or False).

However, I would like to avoid testing all the possible combinations of parameters.

Any suggestions,

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could simply use the `ets()` function in the `forecast` package for R. Would that address your needs? If not, what else do you need?

Comment: @StephanKolassa yes this is what I have been looking for. Do you know the equivalent for python ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of a parallel implementation in Python. I would recommend that you do this exercise in R (which is quite a bit faster than Python, at least in terms of the implementations of auto-ARIMA). Or alternatively, take a look at the source code of `forecast::ets()` and try recreating it in Python...

Comment: smooth another r module also has a similar feature. called es I believe. It chooses among I think thirty or so exponential smoothing models.